# AdMob Interstitial Cocos2d-x WP8

Tags: windows-phone-8, admob, windows-phone-8.1, cocos2d-x, c++-cx

Can enyone tell me how to call AdMob Interstitial between scenes in my cocos2d-x game?

I have tried this http://robwirving.com/2014/07/21/calling-c-methods-c-winrt-components/ guide, but i don't know how to run it from cocos classes.

Is there any another ways, or some guides?

Comment: Sorry my blog post wasn't helpful. Could you link to some of the resources you're looking at? SDK instructions for the AdMob interstitials would be a good place to start

Comment: it was helpful, but i have some missunderstands. https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/wp/interstitial here it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've recently made it. You have to do few things. First of all create helper class, which will help you calling native function (I use this for all 3 platforms, but here's just windows phone):

NativeHelper.h:

```
#ifndef  __NATIVE_HELPER_H_
#define  __NATIVE_HELPER_H_

#include <string>
#include <functional>
#include "cocos2d.h"

using namespace std;
USING_NS_CC;

#if (CC_TARGET_PLATFORM == CC_PLATFORM_WP8)
namespace cocos2d

{

    public delegate void CSharpShowInterstitialDelegate();

    public ref class WP8NativeEventHelper sealed

    {

    public:

        void WP8NativeEventHelper::SetCSharpShowInterstitialDelegate(CSharpShowInterstitialDelegate^ delegate){

            m_CSharpShowInterstitialDelegate = delegate;

        }

        void CallShowInterstitial();

    private:

        property static CSharpShowInterstitialDelegate^ m_CSharpShowInterstitialDelegate;

    };



}
#endif

class NativeHelper
{
public:
    static void showInterstitial(string adSdk);

#if (CC_TARGET_PLATFORM == CC_PLATFORM_WP8)
    WP8NativeEventHelper^ wp8helper;
#endif

    //instance required only for setting callback
    static NativeHelper* getInstance();

    ~NativeHelper()
    {
        instanceFlag = false;
    }

private:

    static bool instanceFlag;
    static NativeHelper* instance;

    NativeHelper() {};

};

#endif // __NATIVE_HELPER_H_
```

So. We have special C++/CX class Wp8NativeEventHelper, which can "talk" with C#. Here we store a delegate.

How it works:

1. C# is calling SetCSharpShowInterstitialDelegate and passes a delegate to it, which will be remembered in static property.
2. Then C++\CX can call it using CallShowInterstitial.

Now NativeHelperWP.cpp:

```
#if (CC_TARGET_PLATFORM == CC_PLATFORM_WP8)

#ifndef  __NATIVE_HELPER_WP_H_
#define  __NATIVE_HELPER_WP_H_

#include "NativeHelper.h"

void WP8NativeEventHelper::CallShowInterstitial(){

    if (m_CSharpShowInterstitialDelegate)

    {

        m_CSharpShowInterstitialDelegate->Invoke();

    }

}

bool NativeHelper::instanceFlag = false;
NativeHelper* NativeHelper::instance = NULL;

NativeHelper* NativeHelper::getInstance()
{
    if(!instanceFlag){
        instance = new NativeHelper();
        instanceFlag = true;
        instance->wp8helper = ref new WP8NativeEventHelper();
    }

    return instance;
}

void NativeHelper::showInterstitial(){
    NativeHelper::getInstance()->wp8helper->CallShowInterstitial();
}

#endif

#endif
```

Here is just an implementation of CallShowInterstitial. Also in NativeHelper::showInterstitial we're calling C++/CX, which later calls c#.

Now c# code (MainPage.xaml.cs):

outside namespace:

```
using GoogleAds;
```

inside class:

```
  private InterstitialAd interstitialAd;
```

in constructor:

```
WP8NativeEventHelper helper = new WP8NativeEventHelper();
helper.SetCSharpShowInterstitialDelegate(showInterstitial);
```

and also create showInterstitial function:

```
public void showInterstitial() //we recreate interstitial each time, because otherwise it'll show only once, only new requests won't work
{
  interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd("MY_AD_UNIT_ID");
  AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();

  #if DEBUG
  // Enable test ads.
  adRequest.ForceTesting = true;
  #endif


  interstitialAd.ReceivedAd += OnAdReceived;
  interstitialAd.LoadAd(adRequest);
}
```

and finally OnAdReceived:

```
private void OnAdReceived(object sender, AdEventArgs e)
{
  System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Ad received successfully");
  interstitialAd.ShowAd();
}
```

Follow this guide to setup admob: https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/wp/quick-start

Now let's use this.

In HelloWorldScene.h add:

```
#include "NativeHelper.h"
```

In HelloWorldScene.cpp:

```
NativeHelper::showInterstitial();
```

The same way you can show/hide/change position of admob banner for example (however it's buggy so I'm using ad mediation).

Comment: wow, nicely done. Thanks, it seems to work, but i have some issues. This guide is for cocos2d v3.x? I'm using cocos2d 2.x, and it gives me error:    The output filename PhoneDirect3DXamlAppComponent.winmd should match the namespace cocos2d for one of types in the .winmd file. Should i port to cocos 3.x? or just use PhoneDirect3DXamlAppComponent namespace instead of cocos2d?

Comment: Yes this is for cocos2d-x 3.0. I don't use 2.0 version, but I think changing namespace should fix it.

Comment: do you know a way to integrate ads in cocos2d-x 3.6? the new template does not provide a C# project and XAML file is different too

Comment: Use cocos console to make a project. It should be as it was before.

Comment: Dredok is right - latest cocos2d-x generates only C++ projects, not C# as it used to in previous versions.

Comment: [link](http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/project-creation-in-cocos-lacks-windows-phone-project/22506) I've created a question about this. But there's no one who cares to respond me. Maybe if more people with bump this topic we can get what we want.

Comment: Yep, this only works for earlier versions of 3.x. As some point around 3.4 or 3.5 the Cocos2d-x project was changed from a C++/CX (C# and C++) project to a C++ only project. It might be possible to create a C++/CX project for the current cocos2d-x version 3.7, but there also might be a good reason that it was removed and replaced with a C++ project. I asked Dale Stammen, The Microsoft Cocos2d-x guy, to clarify if he knows why the C++/CX project was removed from Cocos2d-x here: http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/please-answer-project-creation-in-cocos-lacks-windows-phone-project/22506/18